# Why is my udev rule not working?

Tags: debian, scripting, raspberry-pi, udev

I need to automatically run my script `/var/www/html/configWWW` when any USB is plugged in to my Raspberry.

UDEV RULE - `/etc/udev/rules.d/myRule.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="****",
ATTR{idProduct}=="****", RUN+="/var/www/html/configWWW"
```

MY SCRIPT - `/var/www/html/configWWW`

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/media/pi/USB/SymSif.xml"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
        (
        echo "it works: $(date)" >> /home/pi/Desktop/test.txt
        )
else
        (
        echo "it does not works: $(date)" >> /home/pi/Desktop/test.txt
        )
fi
```

On the other hand, if i run script from bash `/var/www/html/configWWW`, it works!

Why doesn't my `udev` rule work like my bash command?

Comment: When *any* USB device is connected or when a device with a *specific* vendor and product ID is connected?

Comment: when any USB device is connected, pls.

Comment: Then why are you specifying IDs?

Comment: good point :D So, I remove it. ...one minute later... Still, the same.

Comment: Maybe udev rule cannot run this kind of script, because of the special regime of kernel. Am I right ???

Comment: Perhaps you should rename the file, to ensure it's used first (I believe there is a "don't do anything more" directive for udev, and maybe some other usb rule uses it). A name like "000-my.rules" should make it be among the first.

Comment: Run `udevadm test /dev/sda` as root and see what it says. It may (or may not) give a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I once had similar problems, and it turned out the script has been interrupted by subsequent udev events. The solution was to start it in the background:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]*", RUN+="/sbin/start-stop-daemon -Sqb -x /path/to/myScript.py"
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but it does not help.